# wordpress ограничение на количество вводимых символов

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток!
Можно ли в вордпресс ограничить количество вводимых символов в поле текста.

Именно ВВОДИМЫХ данных. То есть, чтобы в админ-панели нельзя было написать больше символов, чем указано.

Вот это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно. Надо понимать, как вы его выводите, этот текст. К каким типам постов это относится.

Comment: А сколько должно быть разрешено символов и как/чем сделаны эти акции?

Comment: @SeVlad, не совсем понял вопрос.
Допустим 300 символов. Акции выводятся как записи, через цикл, сделаны с помощью "register_post_type"

Comment: Просто если бы до 250, то можно было бы использовать не стандартный texarea, а text в произвольном поле. Это так навскидку..

Comment: Вот надо, чтобы было именно поле context, именно в нем, а не в другом поле.

Comment: Коллеги, подскажите, удалось ли решить вышеописанную ситуацию, если да, то каким образом. Попробовал вышеописанные коды, но не помогло, а сайт и вовсе лег.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если упрощённо, то это можно сделать так:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_content_limit' );
function my_content_limit( $initArray ) {
  $initArray['setup'] = <<<JS
    [function (editor) {
      editor.on('keydown', function( e ) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
          return;
        }
        var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
        var max = 300; // Лимит на 300 символов
        var len = content.length;

        if (len >= max ) {
          alert( 'Вы ввели больше ' + max + ' символов!' );
          tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content.substr(0, max));
        }
      });
  }][0]
  JS;

  return $initArray;
}
```

Разумеется, нужно добавить проверку на тип записи, обрабатывать вставку/удаление текста и т.д. Но основной принцип этот пример демонстрирует.

**UPD:** Всё-таки настоятельно рекомендуется проверять длину строки на стороне сервера, как написал KAGG Design [в своём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785529/198222).

Comment: Обалдеть!!! Не знал, что можно создавать js прямо в functions!! Спасибо!

Comment: Любопытное решение. Плюсанул ))

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так должен выглядеть код в functions.php

```
add_filter('the_content', 'the_content_filter');
function the_content_filter( $content ){
    global $post;
    $max_length = 30;

    if ( 'promo_post' === $post->post_type ) {
        $content = mb_substr( $content, 0, $max_length );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Надо знать, как у вас зарегистрирован тип поста - `promo_post` или как-то иначе.

Comment: Я прошу прощение. Нужно ограничение на ВВОДИМЫЕ данные. Чтобы в админ панели нельзя было ввести значение больше, чем указано.