# WordPress: как можно установить ограничения на количество символов в любых полях при редактировании или сохранении записи?

Tags: wordpress

Здесь [рассказано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785524/wordpress-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2), как можно сделать для поля content. а есть универсальное решение, которое не позволяет в любые поля редактора вводить любое количество символов?

Спасибо.

Comment: Нет универсального решения. Конкретизируйте ваш вопрос, что у вас там - метабоксы, класический редактор, Гутенберг, ACF и т.д.

Comment: Ну для начала , те поля которые присутствуют в решении из коробки.Заголовок, содержание записи (content), метки.Редактор классика.
Но имел ввиду что  поля это поля input с атрибутом value. Скопом нельзя такие поля проверить?

Comment: Сама запись как то по другому организована через body и p

Comment: Кстати у меня не получается там задать вопрос----------------


Примерно так должен выглядеть код в functions.php-------
add_filter('the_content', 'the_content_filter');

function the_content_filter( $content ){

    global $post;

    $max_length = 30;


    if ( 'promo_post' === $post->post_type ) {

        $content = mb_substr( $content, 0, $max_length );

 
   }

    return $content;

}
Надо знать, как у вас зарегистрирован тип поста - promo_post или как-то иначе.
-------------------
Как посмотреть как зарегистрирован тип поста??